# funciones externas en vuejs dentro del mismo archivo js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, funciones

Estoy empezando en esto de vuejs y estoy intentando utilizar el valor de de un input en unas funciones que he creado y mostrar el resultado en una tabla html

Lo que quiero lograr es que al insertar un valor al input, este me realice los calculos que hacen mis funciones y el resultado mostrarlo en la tabla

este es mi archivo js en el cual creo la instancia de vue y tengo las funciones, aclarar que las funciones dandoles una constante fuera de la instancia vue me funcionan bien, pero no puedo entregarles el valor del input

```
const per_atk_hp_def = 1.2;
const buff_atk = 0.5;

const add_atk_set = (atk = 0, percentage) => {
  const calc = atk * percentage
  return calc
};
const buff = (atk = 0, buff) => {
  const calc = atk + atk * buff;
  return calc;
};

const app = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

    atk_i:  '', //input
    atk_added_set: add_atk_set(this.atk_i, per_atk_hp_def),
    atk_buffed_ws: buff(this.atk_added_set, buff_atk),
    atk_buffed_wos: buff(this.atk_i, buff_atk)
  }
})
```

y este seria mi input

```
<input type="number" v-model="atk_i" class="form-control" placeholder="Attack" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==5) return false;" ng-model="number" min="0">
```

y la tabla

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-dark table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="5" class="text-center">
        <span>
          Buff Attack Up
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" width="90px" class="text-center"> Set </th>
      <th scope="col">BASE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">With</th>
      <td>{{atk_buffed_ws}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Without</th>
      <td>{{atk_buffed_wos}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco más qué quieres lograr? y cuál es el problema que tienes actualmente

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza actualice la pregunta

Comment: Creo que tendrías que poner esas propiedades  atk_added_set,   atk_buffed_ws y  atk_buffed_wos en `computed` y no en `data`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ acabo de intentarlo, pero no hace nada.
Corrigo*
ahora sale este error
"Getter is missing for computed property "atk_added_set" " con las 3 que uso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tenías era que estabas esperando que una propiedad del data fuese lo que se llama "reactiva" (Cuando este detecte cambios cambie a su vez las demás). Para que puedas conseguir reactividad debes crear métodos computed que detectan cambios en las variables de las que dependen y actualizan su valor inmediatamente. Esto solo lo puedes hacer dentro del bloque `computed` y una vez defines una propiedad la puedes usar como si fuese una variable mas en tu template (html).

Con los cambios que te propongo a continuación te funcionará

(Pruébalo en página completa para que el input sea visible)

```js
const per_atk_hp_def = 1.2;
const buff_atk = 0.5;

const add_atk_set = (atk = 0, percentage) => {
  const calc = atk * percentage
  return calc
};
const buff = (atk = 0, buff) => {
  const calc = atk + atk * buff;
  return calc;
};

const app = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    atk_i:  '', //input
  },
  computed: {
    atk_added_set() {
      return add_atk_set(this.atk_i, per_atk_hp_def)
    },
    atk_buffed_ws() {
      return buff(this.atk_added_set, buff_atk)
    },
    atk_buffed_wos() {
      return buff(this.atk_i, buff_atk);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-dark table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" colspan="5" class="text-center">
                    <span>
                        Buff Attack Up
                    </span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="90px" class="text-center">Set</th>
                <th scope="col">BASE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">With</th>
                <td>{{atk_buffed_ws}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Without</th>
                <td>{{atk_buffed_wos}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input
        type="number"
        v-model="atk_i"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Attack"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono de maravilla.

Answer (score 0):

No es que no puedas enviarle los valores sino que no existen al momento de invocar la función, esta en pleno proceso de creación y actualización de las variables., por ello debes usar **mounted** que se ejecuta posteriormente cuando ya termino de crear las variables.

Quedaria algo asi

```
const app = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

    atk_i:  '', //input
    atk_added_set: 0,
    atk_buffed_ws: 0,
    atk_buffed_wos: 0
  },
  mounted(){
    this.atk_added_set = add_atk_set(this.atk_i, per_atk_hp_def),
    this.atk_buffed_ws = buff(this.atk_added_set, buff_atk),
    this.atk_buffed_wos = buff(this.atk_i, buff_atk)
  }
})
```

Comment: Lo intente de esta manera tambien, pero no funciono, me funciono con el metodo computed, como lo indico en la respuesta Daniel Rodriguez, muchas gracias de todos modos!